fcm.googleapis.com working but not with https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects
When I am using https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send then my code working fine:
$data_win = [
    "registration_ids" => $data['win_firebaseToken'],
    "notification" => [
        "title" => $data['from_number'],
        "body" => $value,
    ],
];
$dataString = json_encode($data_win);
$headers = [
    "Authorization: Bearer " . $SERVER_API_KEY,
    "Content-Type: application/json",
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt(
    $ch,
    CURLOPT_URL,
    "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataString);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response_arr[] = $response;

But When I am changing:
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send url to new https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/123/messages:send
then it's not working
